# Is that Nginx must be required when deploying node.js app to linux server?

Tags: linux, node.js, nginx

I made node.js application so only left deployment part, I want to deploy it to Ubuntu server, so I bought virtual server hosting.

Firstly I thought it would be easy stuff because just push my code to server, and run `app.js`. perhaps not so difficult. so I searched Google some relevant docs, and I found this : https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/nodejs/ownserver/nginx/oss/trusty/deploy_app.html

The doc has instruction with nginx and passenger content, I don't know why this comes up. Should I install nginx on my linux hosting? I red that, is it related with security reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but I think it would be a good practice !  Nginx is a lightweight, FAST, SECURE, & SCALABLE Web/Proxy server. The world’s busiest websites use NGINX ! It will run as service, it will listen for all traffic coming from, outgoing to the external world (Internet) and in your case, you would want to tell it to listen for web (port 80) traffic, and redirect it to your NodeJS app (running on port 8000 for example); It is really a nice idea, it is transparent, and, if well tuned, it will empower up your website ! Furthermore, Nginx is very suitable for application delivery for web and mobile. The installation and configuration of nginx is very easy, and you should integrate something similar to the bellow example to it in order to get your app open to Internet.

So you can:

Leave the NodeJS app as to run locally and try to install nginx in your Linux Server and proxy the trafic on port 80 to localhost:8000 (port 8000 for example). Something like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.yoursite.com;
client_max_body_size 1000M;

location / {
proxy_pass_header Server;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
proxy_connect_timeout 1000;
proxy_read_timeout 1000;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/; # This is the trick !
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Connection '';
proxy_http_version 1.1;
chunked_transfer_encoding off;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
}

}
```

Comment: why 8080 port come up ? in proxy-pass? is it mistake ?? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to run Nginx in front of a Node.js server.
Check with your host provider what are the ports opened to the public and make your node.js app listen to that port.

Nginx by default listen on port 80, the default http port. Try to make your node app listen to that port too

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is just a web proxy server. There is nothing to do with Ngnix until you want to use two back-end server and load balance  between them. Your node app should run completely fine stand alone.